# Installing Firefox plugins issue

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am trying to install my own firefox plugin. I follow [this](http://devilsworkshop.org/shortest-tutorial-for-firefox-extensiontoolbar-development/) tutorial. But each time this gives me following error:-

```
Firefox could not install the file at 

file:///home/ubuntu/googbar.xpi

because: Install script not found
-204
```

Comment: Do you have correct install.rdf file. If possible, can you share your code? Also make sure that you are packaging the xpi file correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that your file doesn't have an [`install.rdf` file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests). Please note that it needs to be at the top level of the XPI archive. So maybe you made a mistake packing the file and `install.rdf` landed in a subdirectory. You can check the list of files using `unzip -l googbar.xpi` command, it should list `install.rdf` without a directory name before it.